# Convert character array to string in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab

I've a M by N matrix, each cell contains a character array, that is an image path. How can I use it to read image? It should be string.

It's what I try to do:

```
imread(fl(1,1));
??? Error using ==> imread>parse_inputs at 491
The filename or url argument must be a string.

Error in ==> imread at 336
[filename, fmt_s, extraArgs, msg] = parse_inputs(varargin{:});
```

And it's my matrix:
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace `fl(1,1)` with `fl{1,1}`. You access the contents of a cell-array with `{}`. You access the cell element itself with `()`.

Since `imread` expects a string and not a cell element, it throws that error.

Comment: There is no "cell element".  For cell matrices, the `()` operator returns a (sub-)cell matrix.  It just happens that when you pass in scalars (as opposed to vectors), the returned cell is of size 1-by-1.